# Inserting data on AnimatedList inside AsyncValue using GlobalKey not working, because AnimatedListState.currentState is null

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have an `AnimatedList` that I want to populate its value using `AsyncValue`. From my understanding in this, the function `initializeItem` shoudn't running, because it depends on *reload* to be *true* to run, but *reload* is *false* at default. When I run this, it return an *exception* `markNeedsBuild() called during build` which from `alkey.currentState` that is **null**. I've tried to change the position for *AnimatedList* and/or `alkey` to *Takok* or load it as *provider*, but still none to work. Is it because `AnimatedList` is depending on `Asyncvalue` data to build? Like before `AsyncValue`'s `data` is delivered, it'll render either the `error` or `loading`, so that `AnimatedList` is not rendered, that's why `alkey.currentState` is **null**.

Here is the data from `Asyncvalue` (**minimum example**):

```json
{
  "page": 1,
  "totalpage": 7,
  "texts": [
    "asdadff",
    "adsfsg",
    "imskrf"
  ]
}
```

Should I split the result of `AsyncValue` data? separating **page** and **totalpage** from **texts**? or you guys have better approach? Thank you.
Below is a minimal code from what I've done.

```dart
class Takok extends StatefulWidget {
  const Takok({super.key});

  @override
  State<Takok> createState() => _TakokState();
}

class _TakokState extends State<Takok> {
  bool reload = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListBody(
        query: {},
        reload: reload,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            reload = true;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class ListBody extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const ListBody({super.key, required this.query, required this.reload});
  final Map<String, dynamic> query;
  final bool reload;
  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _ListBodyState();
}

class _ListBodyState extends ConsumerState<ListBody> {
  List<String> listvalue = [];
  final alkey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  late bool reload;

  void initializeItem(List<String> l, List<String> s) {
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      l.add(s[i]);
      alkey.currentState!.insertItem(i);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    reload = widget.reload;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dataFromAPI = ref.watch(providerData(widget.query));
    return dataFromAPI.when(
      data: (data) {
        if (reload) {
          initializeItem(listvalue, data.texts);
        }
        return AnimatedList(
          key: alkey,
          initialItemCount: listvalue.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
            if (listvalue.isEmpty) {
              return const Text('no data');
            } else {
              reload = true;
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('index ke $index'),
              );
            }
          },
        );
      },
      error: (error, stackTrace) => Text(error.toString()),
      loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```